# fastest way in python to enumerate all combinations and return the index

Tags: python, combinations

It is hard to describe my problem in the title. I think the title of this problem is not very good. My problem is the following

Say I have a list [0,0,0,0,0], I want to put 3 ones into these 5 slots in the list. I want to enumerate all the possible combinations. In this case, it will be 5 choose 3, which is 10， e.g.,

```
[1,1,1,0,0]
[1,0,1,0,1]
....
```

I wish eventually, to get a list of lists such that each element (which is still a list) in the big list, stores the index of those ones in each scenario, e.g., in the example above, the 1st element in the final big list should be [0,1,2], the 2nd element in the final big list should be [0,2,4]...

Is there a fast way of achieving this? I guess I need to use the library itertools, but not sure which specific function should I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

To get all the possible binary lists of length 5 with 3 ones

```
N = 5
zeros = [0]*N
for comb in itertools.combinations(range(N), r = 3):
    l = zeros.copy()
    for indice in comb:
        l[indice] = 1
```

Not very efficient, but should be fast enough.

To get the "big list" of indices, use `itertools.combinations(range(5), 3))`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
from itertools import combinations    
num_ones = 3
slots = 5
comb_indices = list(combinations(range(5),3))
print comb_indices
```

`[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`